# Mixing Cryptomatte

Tags: compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

I have a problem. I made 2 renders with diffrent lighting and first I wanted to separate parts of them using cryptomatte and than combine them, but fore some reson one part is partly transparent[image]

Comment: I think I would need to see the blend file before I could help.  Can you add it? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I can't shere it